# Erlang Maps : get keys that has the same value

Tags: erlang, maps

I have a {H,VV} pair and I want to compare this pair against the rest of the Map to find other key that has the same value.

I tried this:

```
check(H,Map)->
  VV=maps:get(H,Map),
  Fun = fun(K,V) when H =/= K, V=:=VV->
  io:format("~p~p~n",[H,K])
  end,
  maps:map(Fun,Map).
```

it compiles but raise error "function_clause"

Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: What are the arguments you pass in when calling the function?

Comment: "H" is the key that has the value VV; I want to find other keys in "Map" that has the same value "VV"

Comment: You're walking over the entire map, so you're going to eventually hit the `H` key. But your function does not handle that key.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're passing to `maps:map/2` does not handle the `H` key nor any value not equal to `VV`. Try this instead:

```
check(H,Map)->
    VV=maps:get(H,Map),
    Fun = fun(K,V) when H =/= K, V=:=VV->
                 io:format("~p:~p~n",[H,K]),
                 V;
             (_,V) -> V
          end,
    maps:map(Fun,Map).
```

I think you're better off using `maps:fold/3` for this case, though, since you're not trying to create a new map, but rather just want to know the other keys with the same value as `H`. Consider the approach below:

```
check(H, Map) ->
    VV = maps:get(H,Map),
    maps:fold(fun(K,V,Acc) when K /= H, V =:= VV ->
                     [K|Acc];
                 (_,_,Acc) ->
                     Acc
              end, [], Map).
```

This version returns a list of keys that have the same value as `H` in `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

There are list comprehension solutions for this as well:

```
VV = maps:get(H,Map),
[ K || K <- maps:keys(Map), K =/= H, VV =:= maps:get(K, Map) ].
```

Or

```
VV = maps:get(H,Map),
[ K || {K, V} <- maps:to_list(Map), K =/= H, V =:= VV ].
```